# Have an HTML/CSS display issue - text is on image instead of next to image

Tags: html, css

I am doing a short Web Dev course on Udemy and really enjoying it. The webpage I am working on is not displaying correctly. I will include a screen capture below. The image and the text should be side-by-side with the image on the left but the image is on the text.

```html
<HTML>
    <head>
        <title>Small Business Page</title>
        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        
        <!-- Javascript -->
        <script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- <script> //removed for adding in Bootstrap
            $(document).ready( function() {
                // code
                alert("Welcome To myPage With JQuery!");
            });
        </script>  -->
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Header -->
        <header>
            <!-- Main container -->
            <div class="container">
                <!-- single row -->
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- Column left -->
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="images/home.jpg" alt="Small Business Page">
                    </div>
                    <!-- Column right -->
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <h1>LoSo</h1>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Take a Tour</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </body>
    </HTML>
```

I am not sure why this is not displaying correctly. When I inspect the elements on the Chrome Dev Tools tab I don't see anything jumping out at them.

[image: Text should be on the right of the image]
Any advice on how I should move forward would be appreciated.

Martin.

Comment: Please add your `css/style.css` code here, that would help addressing your issue.

Comment: body {
    padding-top: 100px;
    font-family: Ariel, sans-serif;
    color: #333;
}
/* Footer */
footer-p {
    padding: 30px 0px;
}

Comment: I am not concerned about the CSS in the style.css as above as the grid box css is coming from the bootstrap file.

Answer (score 1):

hello the bootstrap version you use is wrong with the class I guess you are using the 4.x version but you wrote 3.x as html you should check this first and you should specify this in this question

Comment: Thanks for your comments @Muhittin GÜLAP I appreciate it. How do I know what class I should be using for my version of bootstrap. Please bear in mind while I have a programming background I am new to HTML/CSS.

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/ You can learn from this link from the document.

Comment: I have been re-reading your comment to ensure I understand. I checked and my bootstrap version is v4.4.1. I did not say that my bootstrap version is 3.x but my JQuery version is 3.x. Does the bootstrap version have to match the JQuery version? I'm just not getting why I can't use the version v4.4.1 bootstrap container class?

Comment: sorry if you change it as below the problem will be fixed

<img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="images/home.jpg" alt="Small Business Page" style="width:100%;">

Comment: Lol it worked! Thanks so much for helping me out @Muhittin GÜLAP